# Performance of `std::vector` vs `std::queue`

Tags: c++, vector, stl, queue

I have submitted a solution to [this problem on spoj.com](http://www.spoj.com/problems/BITMAP/), a site which poses problems to which you can submit solutions which are then judged and given one of three results - accepted, wrong answer, or time limit exceeded. The particular problem I am working on has a time limit of 4 seconds.

My first solution uses `std::vector` and is as follows:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define inf 10000000
typedef pair<int,int> pii;

int main()
{
int t,n,m;
cin>>t;
char str[200][200];
int dist[200][200];
while(t--)
    {
    cin>>n>>m;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%s",str[i]);

    set< pii > ms;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
            {
            if(str[i][j]=='1')
                { dist[i+1][j+1]=0;   ms.insert( make_pair<int,int> (i+1,j+1));  }
            else
                dist[i+1][j+1]=inf;
            }
        }
    int dis=0,rr,cc,p,q;
    pii pi,temp;
    pii nei[5];

    while(ms.empty()==0)   // bfs
        {
            pi=*ms.begin();
            p=pi.first;
            q=pi.second;
            ms.erase(ms.begin());

            vector< pii > v;
            v.push_back(make_pair<int,int>(p,q));

                while(!v.empty())
                {
                    temp = *v.begin();
                    v.erase(v.begin());

                    nei[1].first=temp.first-1; nei[1].second=temp.second;
                    nei[2].first=temp.first+1; nei[2].second=temp.second;
                    nei[3].first=temp.first;   nei[3].second=temp.second+1;
                    nei[4].first=temp.first;   nei[4].second=temp.second-1;

                    for(int i = 1; i<=4; ++i)
                    {
                        rr=nei[i].first;
                        cc=nei[i].second;

                        if(rr>=1 && rr<=n && cc>=1 && cc<=m )
                            {
                                dis=abs(rr-p) + abs(cc-q);

                                if(dist[rr][cc] >dis)
                                    {
                                    dist[rr][cc]=dis;
                                    v.push_back(make_pair<int,int>(rr,cc));
                                    }
                            }
                    }
                }
        }

for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
    for(int j=1;j<=m;j++)
        {
        printf("%d ",dist[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }

}   // end of test case

}
```

When I submitted this, I got "time limit exceeded" as my result. However, on ideone [it gives the correct result in 0s](https://ideone.com/EBQucG).

My second solution uses `std::queue`:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define inf 10000000
typedef pair<int,int> pii;

int main()
{
int t,n,m;
cin>>t;
char str[200][200];
int dist[200][200];
while(t--)
    {
    cin>>n>>m;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) 
        scanf("%s",str[i]);

    set< pii > ms;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
            {
            if(str[i][j]=='1') 
                { dist[i+1][j+1]=0;   ms.insert( make_pair<int,int> (i+1,j+1));  }
            else 
                dist[i+1][j+1]=inf;
            }
        }
    int dis=0,rr,cc,p,q;
    pii pi,temp;
    pii nei[5];

    while(ms.empty()==0)   // bfs 
        {
            pi=*ms.begin();
            p=pi.first;
            q=pi.second;
            ms.erase(ms.begin());

            queue< pii > v;
            v.push(make_pair<int,int>(p,q));

                while(!v.empty())
                {
                    temp = v.front();
                    v.pop();

                    nei[1].first=temp.first-1; nei[1].second=temp.second;
                    nei[2].first=temp.first+1; nei[2].second=temp.second;
                    nei[3].first=temp.first;   nei[3].second=temp.second+1;
                    nei[4].first=temp.first;   nei[4].second=temp.second-1;

                    for(int i = 1; i<=4; ++i)
                    {
                        rr=nei[i].first;  
                        cc=nei[i].second;

                        if(rr>=1 && rr<=n && cc>=1 && cc<=m )
                            {
                                dis=abs(rr-p) + abs(cc-q);

                                if(dist[rr][cc] >dis)
                                    {
                                    dist[rr][cc]=dis;
                                    v.push(make_pair<int,int>(rr,cc));
                                    }
                            }
                    }
                }
        }

for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
    for(int j=1;j<=m;j++)
        {
        printf("%d ",dist[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }

}   // end of test case

}
```

This solution also [produces the correct answer in 0s on ideone](https://ideone.com/TfJ7eO) and was accepted at spoj.com.

In both the cases, the container acts like a "standard queue data structure", whether it is implemented as a `std::vector` or a `std::queue`. Can anyone explain why the first might have been rejected as being too slow while the second was accepted?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve !!

Comment: Please explain your problem properly. I had to read the rules of the site on the first link you gave, then follow a chain of URLs to run your ideone samples, and then re-read your question, before I understood it. Instead, post all relevant details and code samples directly into the question.

Comment: i was unable to post more than 2 urls ( due to low reputation ), hence i had to use series of links ..

Comment: As I already said, post the details directly into the question. Stackoverflow has markup specifically for posting code, and you should describe the relevant parts of how spoj.com works in the question, and merely provide a link as a reference point. Use ideone to e.g. establish that a piece of code compiles successfully, not as a storage place for your code. A question should stand in it's own right and not rely on having to read third party sites to complete it. URLs can easily break, rendering the question useless to future readers.

Comment: I edited your post to give you an idea of how to better word questions for future reference. However bear in mind that this question would probably still be off-topic for Stackoverflow and might be better suited to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @coolcoder Thoroughly read the link I posted in my 1st comment and all the other interesting stuff provided at the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting questions here! Or take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 1st at least!

Comment: thanks :) i was unaware of all these ... these things will be kept in mind while posting questions for the next time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a queue, use a queue.

In your implementation using a vector<>, you are manually erasing the first element of the vector at each iteration, a costly operation on a vector (causing possible reallocation of the entire buffer), but not on a queue (designed specifically for this type of operations _ front and back modifications).

This explains why the vector based implementation is slower.